# How can i prevent a jquery function from running?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, click

i bind a function on a class. I have a table with a class "blanks-table". And i bind a click-function on each tr:

```
jQuery(function(){
    ieClick('.blanks-table tr','click');
});

function ieClick(h_list, h_class){
    if(!h_class) var h_class = 'click';
    jQuery(h_list).click(function(){
        jQuery(this).toggleClass(h_class)
    });
}
```

This is my table:

```
<table class="blanks-table">
   <tr class="sum master">
      <td class="check-holder"><div class="blankcheck"><span class="toggle-show sh"></span></div></td>
      <td>Hello World</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

If i click in the row the color will change. It works great. But i dont like to change the color if i click on the span with the class "sh". In this case i dont like to toggle the class of the row.

Is there any exclude option on bindung the event?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current event is bound to the `tr`- but you can't click directly on a `tr`, only its contents, ie the `td`s and `div`s within that `tr`.

So jquery "*bubbles*" up the event from where it is clicked until it gets an event handler.

In your case that will be the `tr`.

To stop this from happening for specific elements, add a 2nd event handler then call `stopPropagation()` (or `return false`) from the child event handler.

```
$(".sh").click(function() {
    // either of these, as long as return false is last line
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

```js
$("tr").click(() => { console.log("row clicked"); });
$(".sh").click(() => { return false; });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="blanks-table">
   <tr class="sum master">
      <td class="check-holder"><div class="blankcheck"><span class="toggle-show sh">no click area</span></div></td>
      <td>click here for row</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

---

There are other answers on SO that explain event bubbling in more detail, but they all start from the knowledge of the concept, while this introduces the concept